# Binding a FormView to a DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, odbc

Im forced to use ODBC, and i would like to bind a DataSet to a FormView. So far i have this code:

```
Sub lookup(data As String, city As String)

    Dim query As String = "SELECT FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.STREET_NAME, FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.ZIPCODE, UXOR_CITY_DK.NAME AS cityName FROM UXOR_CITY_DK " & _
    "Join(FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL) " & _
    "ON UXOR_CITY_DK.KOMMUNE_KODE=FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.MUNICIPALITY_CODE WHERE UXOR_CITY_DK.NAME = '" & city & "' " & _
    "LIMIT 5"

    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ODBCDataConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim initialDataSet As New DataSet("initial")
    Dim dt As DataSet = GetDataSetFromAdapter(initialDataSet, connectionString, query)

    FormView1.DataSource = dt
    FormView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Public Function GetDataSetFromAdapter(ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet

    Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

        ' Open the connection and fill the DataSet. 
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter.Fill(dataSet)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        ' The connection is automatically closed when the 
        ' code exits the Using block. 
    End Using

    Return dataSet
End Function
```

FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Ingen data">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Postnummer: <%#Eval("MUNICIPALITY_CODE") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Indbyggere: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Geografisk lokation: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Roskilde ligger i <a href="#">Roskilde kommune</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br /><h3><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Borgmester: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Antal veje i kommunen: #</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

I have verified the query and querystring, both work. The FormView does not get populated with the above code. Is it possible to bind a FormView to a DataSet? or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed a few things you probably need to change here. Here is your modified function below. The main issue is the connection not being closed. Regardless of what you may read elsewhere, SQL connections are not closed by the `Using` block. However, I am not sure about the `OdbcConnection`. I would recommend including the closing lines just in case.

```
Public Function GetDataSetFromAdapter(ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet

    Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

        ' Open the connection and fill the DataSet. 
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter.Fill(dataSet)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            connection.Close() 'This is necessary to avoid accidental multiple connections.
        End Try
        ' The connection is automatically closed when the 
        ' code exits the Using block. 
    End Using

    Return dataSet
End Function
```

But the real problem I believe is that you are not referencing the table itself. Dataset only contains the tables, you must specify them when binding...

```
Sub lookup(data As String, city As String)

    Dim query As String = "SELECT FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.STREET_NAME, FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.ZIPCODE, UXOR_CITY_DK.NAME AS cityName FROM UXOR_CITY_DK " & _
    "Join(FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL) " & _
    "ON UXOR_CITY_DK.KOMMUNE_KODE=FIND_KORT_VEJ_FUL.MUNICIPALITY_CODE WHERE UXOR_CITY_DK.NAME = '" & city & "' " & _
    "LIMIT 5"

    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ODBCDataConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim initialDataSet As New DataSet("initial")
    Dim dt As DataSet = GetDataSetFromAdapter(initialDataSet, connectionString, query)

    FormView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
    FormView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it makes no difference, the formview is still blank when i use the modified function.

Comment: @user1359448 have you tried putting a breakpoint on the databind? If not, do that and make sure the table has rows and data.

Comment: No, im not developing locally, the code is hosted and im working over FTP. If i run the query directly from Management studio i get data back.

Comment: It turned out to be some very persistent cache. its working perfectly now! thanks :)